# render data in html with templateView django

Tags: django-views

How can I render the data in from the model to the html? The way they describe it in the docs doesn´t work for me. Here is what I have:

```py
class Thema(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, help_text="The title of the Post")
    publication_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date the Post was published.")
    text = models.TextField(max_length=5000,default='kein Textinhalt vorahnden')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bilder = models.ForeignKey(Bilder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    links = models.ManyToManyField(Link)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The View:

```py
from .models import Thema
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    model = Thema
    context_object_name = 'themas'
    template_name = "home/home.html"
```

And the template:

```html
<h2>THEMAS</h2>
<ul>
    {% for thema in themas %}
        <li>{{ thema.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

How can I render the many to many fields? 

thanks for answers
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template assumes that `themas` is a list. But `themas` is actually only one model instance of `Thema`.

```py
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    model = Thema  # model is Thema
    context_object_name = 'thema'  # 'themas' is missleading --> change to 'thema' 
    # because this view only passes ONE Thema to the view
    template_name = "home/home.html"
```

```html
<h1>Thema: {{ thema.title }}</h1>

<h3>Links:</h3>
{% for link in thema.links.all %}
   <li>{{ link }}</li>
{% endfor %}
<h3>Tags:</h3>
{% for tag in thema.tags.all %}
   <li>{{ tag }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```